# How to make ColdFusion wait?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Let's say I have a function called `takesFiveSeconds()`. I want to see the outcome ***after*** it's finished.

```
takesFiveSeconds()
writeDump(outcome);  // don't execute until takesFiveSeconds is finished
abort;

// the rest of the code runs //
```

***How can I accomplish this?*** I understand CF doesn't have promises yet.

---

Here's what I've tried:

[Thread](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/threadjoin.html)

```
thread name="t1"
{ 
    takesFiveSeconds()
} 
thread name="t2"
{ 
    threadjoin("t1",1000); 
    writeDump(outcome);
    abort;
} 
threadjoin("t2");
```

I'm not sure if this works because the site finishes loading before it hits the abort, and I never see the `writeDump`s.

---

Sleep

```
takesFiveSeconds()
Sleep(15000);
writeDump(outcome);
abort;
```

All this does is take an extra long time to tell me `outcome` was dumped before takesFiveSeconds()` finished.

Comment: If your `takesFiveSeconds` actually runs for 5 seconds before returning, you don't need to do anything to wait for it. Otherwise, you've left out part of the description of how `takesFiveSeconds` works. Is it creating its own background thread? How does it *want* to signal completion?

Comment: As @WumpusQ.Wumbley said, if you want the code to wait for the `takesFiveSeconds()` function to complete, then you don't need to do anything other than call the function and then do the `writeDump()`. By spawning a thread you are handing off the processing and _not_ waiting for it to complete. So, basically, do not use `thread` if you want to wait for execution to complete before proceeding. Also, threads have no output, so you will need to move any output (like `writeDump()` out to the main thread/code.

Comment: Working with threads - https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-coldfusion-threads/working-with-threads.html

Comment: have you actually tried your first code snippet? it should work the way you have it written if takesFiveSeconds actually takes five seconds.

Comment: There's something weird going on. This code is part of a migration task, so it could be running by a different process, but the lead dev says its running synchronously, so it *should* be waiting, but it's not. Unfortunately, what I was trying to accomplish was deemed unnecessary, so I can't spend more time looking into it. I'll try to take a look when I have some free time and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple approach:

```
<cfset start_time = now()>
<cfloop condition="DateDiff('s', start_time, now()) LT 5">
     <cfset tmp = "wait">
</cfloop>
```